# find if two dataset are identical, one in .NET and one in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I have to find if two dataset are identical without using primary key, only data.

**If it exist, I have to return the primary key otherwise I have to insert a new row and return the new primary key**

Instead of comparing each field individually, since I think this could be slow????, I came up with this solution

(I'm going to take an address as an example)

On the SQL Server side, a `persisted` `computed column` with an `index` on it;

```
-- nice new function in 2012; concat
hashbytes('SHA2_256',
    concat(
        nchar(0x2460),[Address_Type_Id],
        nchar(0x2461),[Street_Name],
        nchar(0x2462),[Municipality],
        nchar(0x2463),[Postal_Zip_Code],
        nchar(0x2464),[Unit],
        nchar(0x2465),[Street_Number],
        nchar(0x2466),[PO_Box],
        nchar(0x2467),[Rural_Route_Number],
        nchar(0x2468),[Street_Type_Id],
        nchar(0x2469),[Country_Type_Id],
        nchar(0x246A),[Country_Division_Type_Id],
        nchar(0x246B),[Country_Division_Other],
        nchar(0x246C),[Direction_Type_Id]
    )
)
```

on the .NET side;

```
using(var mySHA256 = System.Security.Cryptography.SHA256Managed.Create())
{
    var Value = string.Concat(
            (char)0x2460, PartyAddress.AddressTypeId,
            (char)0x2461, PartyAddress.StreetName,
            (char)0x2462, PartyAddress.Municipality,
            (char)0x2463, PartyAddress.PostalZip,
            (char)0x2464, PartyAddress.Unit,
            (char)0x2465, PartyAddress.StreetNumber,
            (char)0x2466, PartyAddress.POBOX,
            (char)0x2467, PartyAddress.RuralRouteNumber,
            (char)0x2468, PartyAddress.StreetTypeId,
            (char)0x2469, PartyAddress.CountryTypeId,
            (char)0x246A, PartyAddress.CountryDivisionTypeId,
            (char)0x246B, PartyAddress.CountryDivisionOther,
            (char)0x246C, PartyAddress.DirectionTypeId);

    var hashValue = mySHA256.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(Value));
}
```

After that I can now compare `hashValue` and the `computed column` and it does work.

My question is, before I start implementing this on MANY other table, should I look at another, better, solution?

**EDIT ****************

to add another solution, field by field comparison, since I'm using entity framework would be like this

```
var addressExist = Tombstone.Addresses
                            .FirstOrDefault(x => 
        x.Address_Type_Id == PartyAddress.AddressTypeId &&
        x.Street_Name == PartyAddress.StreetName &&
        x.Municipality == PartyAddress.Municipality &&
        x.Postal_Zip_Code == PartyAddress.PostalZip &&
        x.Unit == PartyAddress.Unit &&
        x.Street_Number == PartyAddress.StreetNumber &&
        x.PO_Box == PartyAddress.POBOX &&
        x.Rural_Route_Number == PartyAddress.RuralRouteNumber &&
        x.Street_Type_Id == PartyAddress.StreetTypeId &&
        x.Country_Type_Id == PartyAddress.CountryTypeId &&
        x.Country_Division_Type_Id == PartyAddress.CountryDivisionTypeId &&
        x.Country_Division_Other == PartyAddress.CountryDivisionOther &&
        x.Direction_Type_Id == PartyAddress.DirectionTypeId);
```

which generate this query

```
SELECT TOP (1) [Extent1].[Address_Id] AS [Address_Id]
    FROM [dbo].[Address] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE ([Extent1].[Address_Type_Id] = @p__linq__0) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Street_Name] = @p__linq__1) OR (([Extent1].[Street_Name] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__1 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Municipality] = @p__linq__2) OR (([Extent1].[Municipality] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__2 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Postal_Zip_Code] = @p__linq__3) OR (([Extent1].[Postal_Zip_Code] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__3 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Unit] = @p__linq__4) OR (([Extent1].[Unit] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__4 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Street_Number] = @p__linq__5) OR (([Extent1].[Street_Number] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__5 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[PO_Box] = @p__linq__6) OR (([Extent1].[PO_Box] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__6 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Rural_Route_Number] = @p__linq__7) OR (([Extent1].[Rural_Route_Number] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__7 IS NULL))) AND
          (([Extent1].[Street_Type_Id] = @p__linq__8) OR (([Extent1].[Street_Type_Id] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__8 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Country_Type_Id] = @p__linq__9) OR (([Extent1].[Country_Type_Id] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__9 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Country_Division_Type_Id] = @p__linq__10) OR (([Extent1].[Country_Division_Type_Id] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__10 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Country_Division_Other] = @p__linq__11) OR (([Extent1].[Country_Division_Other] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__11 IS NULL))) AND 
          (([Extent1].[Direction_Type_Id] = @p__linq__12) OR (([Extent1].[Direction_Type_Id] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__12 IS NULL)))
```

Comment: Hashing is going to be slow, why not do a straight string/value compare?

Comment: Usage is an important context here. How fast do you need it to be?

Comment: @tia, this would be used in a web application in a bulk match/insert if not found. so it should be able to handle between around 50 to a few hundreds entry in less than 5-10 seconds. right now i'm implementing this in a way that i could easily replace what i'm doing by something else if it's too slow

Comment: @Fredou: Have you looked into SQL Server's `MERGE` statement? Possibly you could use its `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clauses to detect data differences. (This would obviously require you to "upload" the .NET `DataTable` into a temporary SQL Server table first.) I am not sure of the specifics, but this might be worth looking into.

Answer (score 2):

If you think comparing each field is going to be slow, consider your alternative solution which comprises of:

- take each field and append a char
- take each filed and concatenate with another one, repeating this process n times (where is no. of fields)
- computing SHA256 hash

So you just made 2n operation to 2 x (2n + 2n + hash(n)). Plus you're creating lots of string each of which is adding to CPU cycles and memory (strings are immutable in .Net).

You can clearly see which one is going to be slower.

Update:

- Since the hash is calculated and persisted, then you're not incurring 2n overhead, just the processing on .Net side.
- A StringBuilder doesn't magically cause you any savings, especially for such low number of operations.
- Having said that, hashing is probably quicker if you index the hash value on SQL Server. Since you want a generic solution, the performance difference of hashing vs. accessing all those columns can vary. I would advise to run some benchmarks against worst case scenario to see which one performs better.
- One word of caution about appending the char - you're now modifying data. If you can guarantee that the char you're appending will never occur in the actual data, you're good. Otherwise, you yourself are introducing a chance of collision.
- Another idea is that you can exclude comparing NULL values, since you already know they are identical.

Comment: to remove possible collision because some column can be null, I'm appending a char between them. I'm using StringBuilder in c# so the issue of string should not appear. Your saying that doing a where clause in sql with 13 comparison which none of them are in an index with the need to catch null comparison should be faster?

Comment: on sql server side, the hash would be saved in a persisted computed column so it would not be recalculated on the fly

Comment: in my question i'm already saying that it would be an indexed computed column, i also added a field by field comparison example

Comment: Do you want to "Select" a row if all fields match? Earlier I thought that you're pulling the row (thru some other means) and comparing the values. In this case, you seriously need to run some benchmarks. If you create a combined index on all columns, the performance may be identical or faster than your manual hash based compare (given both APP and DB servers have same specs).

Comment: I only want to select the primary key if a match is found

Comment: Ok. So I would still say that run some benchmarks. Hashing is a slow process - whether its slower/faster than Index based access or not, can only be determined by running some benchmarks. Databases have evolved and matured so much and the only true way of knowing this for sure, is to run some benchmarks. You can easily do this via your own code - just log the start/end of your DB access each time. With hashing based approach, make sure you include the hashing time as well. If you want added proof, SQL traces and SQL profiler can give you that info.